# counter using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;

    else
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
    echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
    echo '<br>'."<a href='destroy.php'>Set Counter1</a>";
    ?>
```

the above code was maintaining a counter, each time when user will refresh page it will increment. i want to do same work but with javascript but can't find anything online help plz

Comment: ??? No offense, but... First, learn Javascript, then start writing JS code. This is a VERY, very, very basic and wide open question. You need a tutoring website, not this one. When you have a problem with the JS code you write, THEN ask again.

Comment: Looking at your PHP code, you want a per-user session only counter... But you should give enough explicit context : is it site-wide ? persistent ? per-user ? There are a wide array of Javascript solutions depending on your answers

Comment: What is the reason, you like to implement server-side logic using client-side scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must first figure out what exactly are you trying to achieve. JavaScript runs in the client's browser, so it's not able to alter the $_SESSION in any way on your server, all by itself. If you wish to keep this counter only on the client side, try [setting a cookie via JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Another option would be to keep storing the counter on the server session and incrementing it via AJAX. The problem with things that rely on JavaScript to work is that they are not reliable, because the clients can always choose to disable JavaScript. Maybe a better option would be to embed an iframe which targets the PHP script that increments the counter...

Answer (score 1):

If you refresh the page, the javascript will be loaded again and starts from zero. You have to make counted number persistent by using AJAX (in combination with your php script) or using cookies. On this page you find a small tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't remember any variables after a refresh. You have to save the counts on a server or at the client computer.
If you want your count to be stored at the client you can do it with localstorage:

```
window.onberforeunload=function(){
    localStorage.loads++;
    return true;
}
```

Or using cookies:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
    document.cookie="NAME; VALUE; EXPIRE";
}
```

Notice that localstorage only works in newer browsers with HTML5